# Creating point features along polyline with varying distances?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I have tried different tools to create points along polylines. However, I couldn't find a tool that does this task for varying distances. In ArcGIS 10.3 there is `construct points`, but it is only valid for evenly spaced distances.
I've tried to use QChainage in qgis. It only supports evenly spaced points. In ArcGIS Pro, however, they have `varying distances` tool in their documentation. See [Varying Distance documentation, ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/create-point-features-along-a-line.htm)

For now, I use split line to several lines according to the distances and add points on the end vertix of each line. That works for me for now.

Comment: Where do you keep your data? Can you use PostGIS or SpatiaLite?

Comment: They are all locally stored. I guess yes, even though I didn't install them

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: What did you try?  What are the different tools?  Did it work in ArcGIS Pro?    Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: Have you investigated Linear Referencing?